# Google analytics query explorer pagepath filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am using google analytics query explorer http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ to fetch all pagepath with visits greater than 10. I don't want pages whose url begins with `/Registration`. I tried certain regular expressions as `ga:pagPath == ~^/Registration/*` but was unable to get the desired result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `== ~` which should be `=~`

```
ga:pagPath =~ ^/Registration/*
```

Not sure why its `/*`(people are using this all around!) In regex it should be `/.*`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) I found the syntax for "*Does not match regular expression*" is `!~`. So your expression would be:

```
ga:pagPath!~^/Registration/.*
```